# Populate a property of a mongoose schema with all the data in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a model with articles, and would like to populate an array of **data** with all the documents in a collection.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ArticlesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  path: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  base_headline: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  intro: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  featured_image: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  platform_filter: {
    type: String,
  },
  free_filter: {
    type: String,
  },
  content_type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  data: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DesignProducts' }],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Articles', ArticlesSchema);
```

The **data** property should be populated with all documents in the **DesignProducts** collection.

I tried running this but the **data** array is still empty:

```
Article.findOne({ path: slug }).populate('data').exec();
```

Here is what the **designProducts** model looks like:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const DesignProductsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  intro: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  website: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('DesignProducts', DesignProductsSchema);
```

This array should be populated with all the documents in the DesignProducts collection:
[image]

Comment: the syntax si incorrect try this one `data: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'DesignProducts' , `

Comment: It doesn't work, I don't end up with an array of collection documents for the data property. In fact, there is no data property visible in my json response any longer.